# Carbon, Javascript Date Objects and timezone

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, php-carbon

I'm using the [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) and my event list has this format:

```
{"events":[{"eventid":"7","title":"Events","type":"info","startsAt":"2015-09-24T10:00:00+00:00","endsAt":"2015-09-24T11:00:00+00:00","draggable":"true","resizable":"true"}]}
```

But when my events are displayed in the calendar, it shows 6am instead of 10am.

I'm guessing it has to do the Carbon conversion of my dates?

```
$startAt = Carbon::parse($appointments['appointment_start'])->toATOMString();
```

or  the conversion of my dates to Javascript Date Objects and timezones

```
 $http.get('../api/events').success(function(events) {

 //  Convert dates to Javascript Date Object
 for (var i = 0; i < events.events.length; i++) {
    events.events[i].startsAt = new Date(events.events[i].startsAt);
    events.events[i].endsAt   = new Date(events.events[i].endsAt);
 }
```

Not sure how I should handle this? I guess my event dates (i.e 2015-09-24T10:00:00+00:00 ) should have a different format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

Needed to add the timezone in there:

```
$startAt = Carbon::parse($appointments['appointment_start'], \Auth::user()->timezone)->toATOMString();
```

In your case, the timzone can be set with a variable ($timezone)

```
$startAt = Carbon::parse($appointments['appointment_start'], $timezone)->toATOMString();
```

or hardcoded ('Europe/London') :

```
$startAt = Carbon::parse($appointments['appointment_start'], 'Europe/London')->toATOMString();
```